# How to differentiate between email subscription list and blog subscription list?

Tags: email, subscription

I would like to segregate the emails I collect on my wordpress site, is it possible?

I’d like to separate the emails such that the main subscription emails go to my newsletter list. And visitors have to visit the blog in my website and subscribe to specifically subscribe to blog feed.

So I’ll end up generating 3 email lists from one site:

1. People who subscribe to newsletters only
2. People who subscribe to blog feed only
3. People who subscribe to both

In case this piece of info is of use, I’m using Divi from elegant themes to build my site.

IT noob here so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend using a newsletter plugin. I like using https://mailster.co/ This plugin allows you to create many lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Email Subscribers & Newsletters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-subscribers/) plugin. You can use it to manage all blog post notification emails and newsletters in one single place.